Set default input language via powershell on multilanguage system, Windows 10
Win10x64 LTCS.
I have 3 input languages in the system: English (default), Russian, Ukrainian
The problem is that Russian becomes default after hibernate, the bug. I can cure this by visit the languages list, set Russian as default and set English as default again.
I want to automate this operation using batch file and enter commands like this. I can execute batch on rehibernate:
powershell -command "Set-WinUserLanguageList -LanguageList ru-RU, en-US, ua-UA -Force"
powershell -command "Set-WinUserLanguageList -LanguageList en-US, ru-RU, ua-UA -Force"

But something wrong, need some help


In a comment you note that the problem was that Set-WinUserLanguageList complained about an invalid language passed as part of the array of languages to -LanguageList and, indeed, ua-UA should have been uk-UA (Ukrainian).[1]
You could have avoided the problem if you hadn't hardcoded the array passed to -LanguageList and instead retrieved the list of installed user language programmatically:
# Get the current list of installed user languages (as an array).
$userLangs = (Get-WinUserLanguageList).LanguageTag

You could then simply swap the array's first two entries for your successive Set-WinUserLanguageList calls, and use a single call to powershell.exe, the Windows PowerShell CLI.
Here's the PowerShell code in isolation, spread across multiple lines for readability, with comments (note that the Set-WinUserLanguageList calls emit warnings, which you can suppress with -WarningAction Ignore; the Start-Sleep 1 call (1-second sleep) shouldn't be necessary, but, sadly, is):
# Get the list (array) of user languages.
$userLangs = (Get-WinUserLanguageList).LanguageTag
# Create a copy that has the 1st and 2nd elements swapped.
$userLangsModified = $userLangs[1, 0] + $(if ($userLangs.Count -ge 3) { $userLangs[2..($userLangs.Count-1)] })
# Apply the workaround:
# Set the modified list.
Set-WinUserLanguageList -Force -LanguageList $userLangsModified
# Sleep a little. !! As you've found out, this is necessary
# for the 2nd call to take effect.
Start-Sleep 1
# Switch back to the original list.
Set-WinUserLanguageList -Force -LanguageList $userLangs

And here's the (of necessity) single-line form for your batch file:
@echo off

powershell -c "$userLangs = (Get-WinUserLanguageList).LanguageTag; $userLangsModified = $userLangs[1, 0] + $(if ($userLangs.Count -ge 3) { $userLangs[2..($userLangs.Count-1)] }); Set-WinUserLanguageList -Force -LanguageList $userLangsModified; Start-Sleep 1; Set-WinUserLanguageList -Force -LanguageList $userLangs"


Optional reading: How to test the validity of a culture name / language tag (whether it refers to a predefined culture / language):
It is not obvious how to test this, given that you can call a [cultureinfo] constructor with any name that is formally correct ([a-z][a-z] or [a-z][a-z]-[A-Z][A-Z], although case doesn't matter and there are variations with additional/longer tokens) without causing an error; similarly, the .GetCultureInfo() method doesn't report an error by default.

Windows PowerShell (the legacy, ships-with-Windows, Windows-only edition of PowerShell whose latest and last version is 5.1) / .NET Framework solution:
$cultureNameToTest = 'ua-UA'
$isValid = 
  try { ([cultureinfo] $cultureNameToTest).EnglishName -notmatch 'Unknown Locale' } 
  catch { $false }


Note: Interactively, you can just do something like [cultureinfo] 'ua-UA' and see if the DisplayName column contains substring Unknown Locale or an error is reported.


PowerShell (Core) 7 (the modern, cross-platform, install-on-demand edition) / .NET solution:
# Using the Get-Culture cmdlet
$cultureNameToTest = 'ua-UA'
$isValid = 
  try { [bool] (Get-Culture $cultureNametoTest) } 
  catch { $false }

# Alternatively, using [cultureinfo]::GetCultureInfo() with the
# overload with the `predefinedOnly` parameter
$cultureNameToTest = 'ua-UA'
$isValid = 
  try { [cultureinfo]::GetCultureInfo($cultureNameToTest, $true) } 
  catch { $false }


Note: Interactively, you can just do something like Get-Culture ua-UA and see if an error is reported.




[1] While the call still succeeds for those languages that are valid (you only get a warning stating The list you attempted to set contained invalid languages which were ignored), the original uk-UA (Ukrainian) entry will in effect disappear from the list (since you mistakenly tried to reference it as ua-UA, which was ignored).

If you are executing a PowerShell command in a batch like that you might have problems in 3 places:

The command being executed. Try including the -NoExit parameter to the powershell.exe call so you can catch any script errors. You'll need to remove it later.
The powershell.exe process. If you have syntax problems in the command, or the execution policy is restrictive PowerShell will not execute. Try adding the parameter -ExecutionPolicy Bypass to the powershell.exe call (requires administrator). Also try to execute the raw command in a PowerShell host to see if it gives the expected result.
Syntax or execution problems in the batch file. Instead of executing the batch try calling it from a command prompt, this way when it finishes executing the window will still be open and you can see any errors that it might write to STDERR. Combine this with the -NoExit parameter and you will end up with two windows.

Let me know if it worked for you.

NoExit gave the error, BTW, I called the command in command line, so I see the errors

powershell -command "Set-WinUserLanguageList -LanguageList ru-RU, en-US, ua-UA -Force" - got The list you attempted to set contained invalid languages which were ignored and nothing had happened in settings

rem Switch default input language en->ru->en
CALL powershell -command "Set-WinUserLanguageList -LanguageList ru-RU, en-US, uk-UA -Force"
CALL timeout /t 1
CALL powershell -command "Set-WinUserLanguageList -LanguageList en-US, ru-RU, uk-UA -Force"

Finally the problem was that it necessary to use uk-UA. Doubleswich on rehibernate working well now and I solved the problem with autoswitch to ru inpun language. I made the cmd file and start it on out from hibernate. Tested well in different cases (cmd and hibernate). Schedule event to start: trigger: System - Power-Trobleshooter - 1

As for the general troubleshooting tips: If the batch file runs visibly, there's no need for -NoExit: PowerShell's output will be part of the batch file's output - though placing pause at the end of the batch file will help if the batch file isn't run from an interactive session and the console window auto-closes on exiting the batch file.
If it runs invisibly,  neither -NoExit nor pause is an option, and redirecting command output to file(s) is required, notably including a 2> redirection to capture errors (too).

Specifically, there is no syntax problem in the PowerShell CLI call in the question, and, given that only cmdlets are being called (whose module isn't subject to the execution policy, because it
contains no script elements), the presence or absence of an -ExecutionPolicy argument makes no difference here.
